# Meaning of at least as late in the alphabetical order

Tags: logic, relations

I'm working some problem in Velleman's How to prove book and is faced with a set in it which goes like this:

$R1 = \{(x,y) \in A \times A \mid \text{the word $y$ occurs at least as late in alphabetical order as the word $x$} \}$

$R2 = \{(x,y) \in A \times A \mid \text{the first letter of the word $y$ occurs at least as late in the alphabet as the first letter of the word $x$}\}$

where $A$ is the set of all words of English.

Can someone give sample set of $R1$ and $R2$ and explain what it means ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(apple, apple) and (apple,atom) are each in both $R_1$ and $R_2$, but (atom, apple) is only in $R_2$.

In the dictionary, "apple" comes before "atom".  This explains $R_1$.

In the alphabet, "a" comes at the same place as "a".  This explains $R_2$.